# Vue & Pug - CoffeScript in attributes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, coffeescript, pug

So I'm using **Vue** with the template written in **Pug** and I'd like to use a bit of **CoffeeScript** in the Pug markdown.
Something like this:

```
input( v-model.trim="#[:coffee-script user?.details?.last_name]" type="text" placeholder="Last name")
```

... since `user`, `details` and `last_name` are not guarenteed to exist and I'd like to use **Coffee**'s existential chaining.

But I get an `invalid expression: Invalid or unexpected token in #[:coffee-script user?.details?.last_name]` error.

I also tried `input( v-model.trim=":coffee-script user?.details?.last_name" type="text" placeholder="Email address")` to no avail.

**Is this possible?** If not, is there another, short way of guarding against undefined values?

PS: I did `npm install —save jstransformer-coffee-script`

Comment: Why did you use .trim?

Comment: @Malkev good catch, thank you, I guess I really shouldn't when it comes to last names. Copy-paste programming.